# Are the following statements always true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I keep getting true for the following statements when testing them, but I've never been good with proof by contradiction, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out with the following:

1) For all sets $A$ and $B, A − (B − A) = A.$

2) For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, $A \cup (B − C) = (A \cup B) − C.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $A\setminus(B\setminus A)=A\cap(B\setminus A)^{c}=A\cap(B\cap A^{c})^{c}=A\cap(B^{c}\cup A)=(A\cap B^{c})\cup A=A$.
2. Consider $A=\{0\}$, $B=\emptyset$, and $C=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A\setminus(B\setminus A)=A$$ because
$$A\cap(B\setminus A)=\oslash$$

Answer (score 0):

First one is correct  as mentioned by Michael Rozenberg in his answer. Though the second one is false. For instance take $A=\{1,2,3 \},B = \{2,3,4 \}$ and $C = \{3,4,5 \}$.